# Progress bar within popover

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar, popover

Using Bootstrap I inserted progress bar in a popover (I use it to show some statistics), but the problem is that the progress bar is going outside the border of the popover, this is my code:

```js
$("#sword").popover({ trigger: "hover" , placement: 'top', html:true,
             
              content:  function() {return $("#ppf").html();}       
                 });
```

```html
 <div class="hide" id="ppf">
            <div class="container">
                <h5 class="progress-label"> Others: </h5> <div class="progress" style="">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="66"
  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:66%">66%</div>
                     </div>  
          <br/><br/> 
           
            </div></div>
```

What I can do so that the progress bar stay inside the border of the popover, in addition to still responsive.

Comment: Try changing `container` to `container-fluid`.  The former is fixed width and may be forcing your progress bar to appear wider than the popover.  Alternatively you could remove it entirely; there isn't really a reason to use `.container` if all you are doing is inserting this into a popover.

Comment: @RobertC In reality I've added the container class since I wanted to align the label and progress bar on the same line. Anyway both of your solution are working fine. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to create the sword element then set ppf style="display:none;"

and thats it here is an example of your same code

```
<div id="info" style="display:none;">
  <div class="container">
    <h5 class="progress-label"> Others: </h5>
    <div class="progress" style="">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="66"
      aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:66%">66%
      </div>
    </div><br/><br/>
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn">
  Popover on right
</button>
```

[Example working on JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gmerida/4rt00Lee/)